# replacing post ID by custom post name in url

Tags: permalinks, urls, customization

I am stuck in replacing post ID by custom post name in url. 
link is as shown below:
href="'.$url.'/'.$options['applyp'].'/?pos='.$post[$i]->ID.'"
i need to replace ?pos='.$post[$i]->ID.' by custom postname.. I tried /%postname% but got an error.

The error was something like this.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '">

I also tried by using http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks. I got same error

Can somebody help me in resolving this issue?

regards

Comment: Did you try `permalinks` under `setttings`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Answer (score 1):

Under Settings>Permalinks you merely have to select "Post Name" to get the post name in the permalink. If you are getting parse/syntax errors something else is going on and I suggest you revert to the default theme and disable plugins until you determine where the problem is coming from.

[image: Change permalinks]